# Spring Standalone util schema for collections like list, set

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, arraylist

I am using Spring Tool Suite to demonstrate Standalone util schema for collections like list, set, map but I am getting an error while using the tag

util:list</util:list>

cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'util:list'.
I have included util schema, and on the net, I found I need to import spring security dependency but still it's giving the same error.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:c="http://springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/springutil.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
 https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
             ">
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
   
<util:list id="skillsetList1" list-class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <value>JAVA</value>
    <value>GROOVY</value>
    <value>ORACLE</value>
</util:list>
<bean class="x.y.Person" name="person"
      c:<list_var_in_class>-ref="skillsetList1" />
```